# Material UI modal not working (React JS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to replicate the example of a modal from material ui examples but I can't make it work, first I was getting a "***Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined***" I solved that and now there are no errors in the console but when I click on the button that displays the modal nothing happens.

> Im using material-ui v1.0.0-beta.31

This is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import Typography from 'material-ui/Typography';
import Modal from 'material-ui/Modal';
import Button from 'material-ui/Button';

function rand() {
  return Math.round(Math.random() * 20) - 10;
}

function getModalStyle() {
  const top = 50 + rand();
  const left = 50 + rand();

  return {
    top: `${top}%`,
    left: `${left}%`,
    transform: `translate(-${top}%, -${left}%)`,
  };
}

const styles = theme => ({
  paper: {
    position: 'absolute',
    width: theme.spacing.unit * 50,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    boxShadow: theme.shadows[5],
    padding: theme.spacing.unit * 4,
  },
});

class SimpleModal extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open: false
    };
    this.handleOpen = this.handleOpen.bind(this);
    this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
  }

  handleOpen() {
    this.setState({ open: true });
  };

  handleClose(){
    this.setState({ open: false });
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <Typography gutterBottom>Click to get the full Modal experience!</Typography>
        <Button onClick={this.handleOpen}>Open Modal</Button>
        <Modal
          aria-labelledby="simple-modal-title"
          aria-describedby="simple-modal-description"
          open={this.state.open}
          onClose={this.handleClose}
        >
          <div style={getModalStyle()} className={classes.paper}>
            <Typography type="title" id="modal-title">
              Text in a modal
            </Typography>
            <Typography type="subheading" id="simple-modal-description">
              Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula.
            </Typography>
            <SimpleModalWrapped />
          </div>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

SimpleModal.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};


const SimpleModalWrapped = withStyles(styles)(SimpleModal);

export default SimpleModalWrapped;
```

From the original example the only difference with the code above is that I add the following:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open: false
    };
    this.handleOpen = this.handleOpen.bind(this);
    this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to see the change in state when you are clicking on button to open the modal?? You can check in react dev tools. If that is the case inspect the page to see which styles are being applied to the modal component

Answer (score 2):

Try binding `this` when rendering the button:

`<Button onClick={this.handleOpen.bind(this)}>Open Modal</Button>`

And likewise, for modal,
`onClose={this.handleClose.bind(this)}`, no need for these lines:

```
this.handleOpen = this.handleOpen.bind(this);
this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, I tried binding "this" when rendering the button but same thing, nothing happen, I put a console.log inside handleOpen() just to check if it was working and indeed, I can see the message while clicking the button, I don't get why is not displaying the modal =(

Comment: Strange, everything looks correct. An older project of mine is using `material-ui` (not `material-ui-next`), and the modal dialog is working fine. Perhaps there is a bug

Comment: If you remove the content within the `<Modal></Modal>` tags, and replace it with say `<div>test</div>`, does it work?